# Wrong answers to simple trigonometry questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

I am solving the following questions from [here](https://www.math10.com/en/tests/trigonometry-test/sin-cos-tan-test.html)
I gave the following answers to the questions and are marked as wrong:

> 5. A plane ascends at a 40° angle. When it reaches an altitude of one hundred feet, how much ground distance has it covered? To solve, use
>    the trigonometric chart. Round the answer to the nearest tenth.

Options: $64.3$ft, $76.6$ft, $80.1$ft, $119.2$ft
My answer: $76.6$ft. Reasoning: It is $100\cdot\cos 40º$

> 6. A 20 ft. beam leans against a wall. The beam reaches the wall 13.9 ft. above the ground. What is the measure of the angle formed by the
>    beam and the ground?

Options: $44º, 35º, 55º, 46º$
My answer: $46º$. Reasoning:  $\sin \theta = \frac{13.9}{20} = 0.695$ and $\cos 46º \approx 0.695$

They were marked as wrong. What am I messing up here?

Comment: In problem 5, the value of $\cos(40^\circ)$ tells you how the base relates to the hypoteneuse. However, you don't know the hypoteneuse here: you know the *height*. So you need to use a trigonometric function which connects base to height. The issue is similar in 6.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:Isn't the hypoteneuse $100$ft?

Comment: @NoahSchweber:Hm.I think I got you now. I misunderstood the statement

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1. $\frac{100}{x} = \tan 40^\circ$
   $x = \frac{100}{\tan 40^\circ} \approx 119.2 $
2. $\frac{13.9}{20} = \sin\theta$.
   $\theta = \arcsin(\frac{13.9}{20}) \frac{180^\circ}{\pi} \approx 44^\circ$

Thank you.

**Comments**:
For 1), Refer to Schweber's comment!
In the question 2), you have to find an angle $\theta$ that makes $\sin\theta = 0.695$ but not $\cos\theta = 0.695$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @ChrisLeary I guess there are two possible reasons: 1) The lines in the figure are not straight enough; 2) I did not explain why OP got wrong answers.

Comment: I solved the first one differently i.e. found the hypotyneuse as $100/ \sin 40$ and then multiplied it by $\cos 40$ but that is basically the same formula as yours.

Comment: For the second one, I couldn't remember arcsin, thanks for that. Is that arcsin one multiplication?

Comment: @Hermis14 - Maybe so. In any event, I thought it was a good answer. It left something for the OP to figure out, but had more detail than an answer in an answer key would ever have had. Happy New Year.

Comment: @ChrisLeary Thank you. I wish you a happy new year!

Comment: @Jim $\arcsin$ means the inverse of $\sin$. When you know $a$ but $x$ that makes $a = \sin x$, it gives a desired value by $ x = \arcsin a$. There are many solutions for each $a$, but $\arcsin$ gives you the simplest one. I think this site will help you understanding $\arcsin$: https://www.math.net/calculators/arcsin

Comment: Do I need a calculator for arcsin?

Comment: @Jim Yes, in most cases.